# Is there a way to monitor data in real time with GDB?

Tags: gdb, cross-platform, gdbserver

I am debugging from PC a target device (Cortex M3) with st-link v2 under OpenOCD, and I want to move to "black magic probe", whitch has integrated GDB server. With the first, with the OpenOCD, one can read memory without stopping the program. With GDB it seems that after executing `run` command, there is no way to send other commands. Is there any way to read the memory with GDB without stopping the program?